# flask sqlalchemy and update cascade

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Im writing an inventory app with flask+sqlalchemy, long history made short i have a table called Bill with id, bill_id and bill_date, and the inventory table with id, bill_number, loctation. Then using a queryselectfield the user select the bill_number, fill the others fields and store information in the DB.

but if i update the bill_number in the bill table, need that also the bill_number in the inventory table update all those entries.

I have tried with foreignkey, creating a for statement to update all the entries and nothing works. Also the update method but only works with 'static_values' but with variables got me a literal error.

```
class Bill(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bill_number = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    bill_date = db.Column(db.Date, index=False, unique=False)

class Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

class Inventory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial_number = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    bill_number = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('bill.bill_number'))
    location = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('location.location_name'))

update = Inventory.query.filter(Inventory.bill_number==old_bill).update({ Inventory.bill_number : new_bill})
```

where old_bill and new_bill comes from a form, if a try with:

```
Inventory.query.filter(Inventory.bill_number=='666').update({ Inventory.bill_number : '999'})
```

works like a charm, but i need to use the values from the form, not those static values. Foreignkeys are used but dont know if they really works how in the way that i implemented.

Even tried with:

```
old = form.old.data
new = form.new.data
all = Inventory.query.filter_by(bill_number=old).all()
for i in all:
    i.bill_numer = new
db.session.commit()
```

but no, cant update the entire inventory table.